# How can I show on View the files at local disk (Laravel)?

Tags: laravel, view, storage

I want make files storage on Laravel. Until now I did a symbolic link with command php artisan storage:link. When I save a file it's storage on directory "storage/app/anexos/'filename.extension'". However, when I try show at a View, the error 404 (not-found) is displayed. Bellow following some screenshot.

On View:

```
<div class="container mt-3">

        <img src="{{ asset("storage/app/anexos/$amostra->anexoURL") }}">

</div>

//$amostra->anexoURL is a nameFile that is saved on my table 'amostras'
```

On Controller

```
        $nameFile = null;

        if ($request->hasFile('anexo') && $request->file('anexo')->isValid()) {

            $name = uniqid(date('HisYmd'));

            $extension = $request->anexo->extension();

            $nameFile = "{$name}.{$extension}";

            $upload = $request->anexo->storeAs('anexos', $nameFile);

            if ( !$upload )
                return redirect()
                            ->back()
                            ->with('error', 'Falha ao fazer upload')
                            ->withInput();
        }

        $url = $nameFile;
```

[Saving a image, after that I get just name file and save on db on table amostra to make a relationship between the image and 'amostra'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM2Ox.png)

[On View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MTXX.png)

[The address on inspector element browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef3sa.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can understand what you are asking. Also take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting an answer. And [Why not upload images of code when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Then, please update your question and add the code there not as linked images.

Answer (score 0):

The Asset() function you are using is going to search in /public folder, but your image is saved in /storage folder.
Try using:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url($amostra->anexoURL) }}">
```